# Security issue for landing doors and cabin doors in an elevator control board (PIC16F877)

Tags: microcontroller, homework

I am working on a control board for an elevator as part of my final year project. I am currently working on the safety aspect for the landing doors and cabin doors, and I am using Proteus to simulate my circuit.

I have isolated the two voltages (230V and 5V) using optocouplers, but I have not been able to detect the presence of voltage on pin RB1. I want to read the result and turn on the LED, which is the output of pin RB1, if pin RA1 is in a high signal state.

Description:

- The 2W input resistor is properly sized: it should effectively dissipate 0.35W.
- Smoothing is done by C1 of 100 uF.
- The current flows through an LED displaying the presence of voltage on J1, then through the optocoupler.

[image]

---

"My problem is that I don't know why the RB1 pin is not receiving anything. I can't turn on the D3 LED without the RA1 pin being in the high state. My schematic seems correct and I'm sure my code is correct too."

---

I am working on the security part of my electronic card, which controls an elevator (i.e., a motor). If the landing doors and the cabin doors are closed, it means a closed circuit and the motor runs, and the elevator goes up or down depending on the operator's call. Imagine the doors as a switch. Since I am controlling an elevator in a four-story building, I need a voltage of 230V. As a workaround, I inserted an alternating voltage V2 in my circuit to isolate two parts of the voltage. The first part is 230V, and the second part is 5V so that I can work with the microcontroller.
I have placed the LED D2 as an indicator to know if the security part is functioning. This means that if the LED D2 does not light up, then the motor is not running in safety mode.

Comment: What do you measure on U1? How much current is passing on the LED? What voltage do you read on collector pin?

Comment: Hello,

I would like to apologize for posting my previous question in French on this English-speaking forum. I have since corrected my question in English to comply with the community rules.

Thank you for your understanding.

Comment: Bonjour et bienvenue ... et anglais parfait, en plus.  Merci.

Comment: I see in the diagram that the LED is connected to `earth-ground` while the CPU appears to be connected to `chassis-ground`.  Are these connected elsewhere?  If not, the bottom of the LED is floating.

Comment: I'm not making any sense of the circuit to the lower left. First you have a bridge rectifier from... something. And then D2 and U1 in series. And then some volt meter thing saying you should have 3.23V at that spot, in which case the forward voltages of D2 + U1 are possibly too large. What current is this calculated for (if at all calculated)?

Comment: It's not clear from your question whether you've written any code for your PIC yet. Have you written code to properly configure and read the state of RA1? What result do you get when you stimulate the running code? Are you able to "manually" toggle the RB1 output in a loop (without taking the state of the RA1 input into account)?

Comment: C1 should not be used (or very lower value ...). Idem for C3.

Comment: This seems to work, there is no high signal at pin RA1 if the AC voltage V2 is present. The transistor in the coupler is conducting. If pin RB1 follows RA1 as you describe, the output LED D3 will be off. Never open the button in the input path! C1 will charge up above 300 V and if the button is closed in this condition, the LED D2 and the LED in the coupler most likely will be blown.

Comment: @NaderNoomen - Hi, You wrote two "answers" but they actually more info, not solutions, so they have been added to your question as edits (i.e. updates) instead. || Since you asked the question, unless you are writing the *full & final* answer to that question (i.e. you don't need further help & you solved the problem yourself using a different solution than any answer) please don't use the box labeled "Your Answer" below. Instead, to add more info / clarification, please [edit] the question. Or *comment* to respond to a minor point (which is not additional info that should be in the question).

Answer (score 0):

The lower left of your picture should be something like this ...

[image]

In place of ... ("too much" filtering ...)

[image]